# How are we able to use variables inside HTML tags in a node environment?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

This is not my code. My question is, how are the stuff like '+result+' showing up in the html tags, and in the values of the input textboxes in the post response, how is it valid?...
Also, on a side note, why is it when I do response.write(form), followed by response.end() as a replacement for response.end(form), that the code stops working. I'm new to node, so please dumb it down.

```
    // Load the http module to create an http server.
    var http = require('http'); 

    // Create a function to handle every HTTP request
    function handler(req, res){

  var form = '';

  if(req.method == "GET"){ 

    form = '<!doctype html> \
    <html lang="en"> \
    <head> \
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  \
    <title>Form Calculator Add Example</title> \
    </head> \
    <body> \
  <form name="myForm" action="/" method="post">\
      <input type="text" name="A"> + \
      <input type="text" name="B"> = \
      <span id="result"></span> \
      <br> \
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"> \
     </form> \
     </body> \
    </html>';

  //respond
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(form);

  } else if(req.method == 'POST'){

    //read form data
    req.on('data', function(chunk) {

      //grab form data as string
      var formdata = chunk.toString();
    console.log(formdata);
      //grab A and B values
    console.log(formdata.split("&")[0]);
      var a = eval(formdata.split("&")[0]);
    console.log(a);
      var b = eval(formdata.split("&")[1]);

      var result = calc(a,b);

      //console.log(chunk.toString());
      //console.log(a);
      //console.log(b);
      //console.log(result);

      //fill in the result and form values
    form = '<!doctype html> \
    <html lang="en"> \
    <head> \
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  \
    <title>Form Calculator Add Example</title> \
    </head> \
    <body> \
   <form name="myForm" action="/" method="post">\
      <input type="text" name="A" value="'+a+'"> + \
      <input type="text" name="B" value="'+b+'"> = \
      <span id="result">'+result+'</span> \
      <br> \
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"> \
    </form> \
    </body> \
    </html>';

    //respond
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(form);

    });

    } else {
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end();
    };

    };

    //js functions running only in Node.JS
    function calc(a,b){
    return  Number(a)+Number(b);;
    }

    http.createServer(handler).listen(8080, function(err){
  if(err){
    console.log('Error starting http server');
  } else {
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8080/");          
    };
    });
```

Comment: Node.js does not know about HTML. What you are seeing are ordinary ([multiline](http://stackoverflow.com/q/805107/1048572)) string literals, and those can of course be concatenated with strings from variables.

Comment: What exactly does "*stops working*" mean? Are you getting exceptions? What's the output you can see in the browser?

Comment: I'm talking about, say this part:   <span id="result">'+result+'</span>. What is this called? As for the "stops working" I mean that the server no longer connects, so it won't load the page for some reason.

Comment: Note that you should not concatenate text with HTML. you need to make sure you encode any text as HTML before inserting it into your HTML, otherwise you open the door to issues with some characters, and to XSS attacks. Likewise, the code is pretty bad about handling properly encoded submitted data.